# Implementing both controltemplate and datatriggers for a textbox control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, datatrigger

I'm new to WPF....I have tried implementing controltemplate and datatriggers both for textbox..I want to change the background color of the textbox when the value entered in that is not "18" through datatriggers..(i want the controlproperty for the textbox to work as it is)how can i achieve it.... 
the Xaml code written is as follows:

```
    <TextBox x:Uid="txtagevals" x:Name="txtAge" Height="25" Width="80" Background="Wheat"  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
        <TextBox.Template>
            <ControlTemplate x:Uid ="txtagevals" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                    BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="5">
                      <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Age}" Value="18">
                    <Setter TargetName="" Property="Text" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```

can anybody please help me...Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code to validate text in textbox :

```
<TextBox x:Uid="txtagevals" x:Name="txtAge" Height="25" Width="80">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="18">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
```

In your code, you can do like this

```
 <TextBox x:Uid="txtagevals" x:Name="txtAge" Height="25" Width="80" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
                <TextBox.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate x:Uid ="txtagevals" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  
                    BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="5">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="18">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </TextBox.Template>
            </TextBox>
```

You can bind gridview like below, it's working fine for me :

```
<ListView Name="lstTest">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="100">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox x:Uid="txtagevals" x:Name="txtAge" Height="25" Width="80" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Text="{Binding Path=Age}">
                                        <TextBox.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBox.Style>
                                        <TextBox.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate x:Uid ="txtagevals" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  
                    BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="5">
                                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                                                </Border>
                                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="18">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </TextBox.Template>
                                    </TextBox>
                                </DataTemplate>

                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you..that worked for the "textbox" background property changed..but when i click button with changed value in the textbox to bind the value in the gridview ... the old value of the textbox is binding again in the gridview its not taking the changed value in the textbox.. can you please help me how to bind the changed textbox value to the gridview..

Comment: not only the above... the gridview is not at all getting bind with the value=18 from the textbox..please tell me how to resolve it..thank you.

Comment: That's great...but now am able to bind any value to gridview but still not able to bind "value=18" to the gridview from the textbox..when am trying to bind it with "18".. the gridview is just taking it as "0"...can you please tell me why..

Comment: i mean when i try to bind the gridview at first with value=18 its taking as "0"..else the gridview is taking the previous value binded to it from textbox..

Comment: How it's possible ? it should take whatever you bind from code. Can you please give me your binding code in details ?

Comment: am sorry..In my scenario the "textbox" is not placed inside the gridview or gridview structure..am trying to bind the values entered in the textbox(placed in a tabcontrol-tab1) to the gridview in the tabcontrol(placed in another tab-tab2)...i hope you get my context..

Comment: ObservableCollection<EmpTemp> Empdata = new ObservableCollection<EmpTemp>();

 //the following is the code for the button_click event
{
 Dataclass dtclass = new Dataclass{  };// class for defining properties
 dtclass.Names = txtNames.Text;
 dtclass.Age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);
 dtclass.Description = txtDesc.Text;
 Empdata.Add(new EmpTemp(dtclass.Names, dtclass.Age, dtclass.Description));
 listview1.DataContext = Empdata;// listview1 -- is the listview in which i placed the gridview
 displaytab.Focus();
 displaytab.IsEnabled = true;
}

Comment: //observablecollection class implementation
 public class EmpTemp
        {
            public string empname { get; set; }
            public int empage { get; set; }
            public string empdesc { get; set; }
            public EmpTemp(string name, int age, string descript)
            {
                empname =  name;
                empage = age;
                empdesc = descript;
            }
        }

Comment: <TabItem Header="Second" Uid="tab2" x:Name="displaytab">
  <Grid>
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="listview1">
  <ListView.View>
  <GridView x:Uid="grdv1" x:Name="grdviewemp">
  <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=empname}"/>
  <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=empage}"/>
  <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=empdesc}"/>
  </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
  </Grid>
  </TabItem>

Comment: Change binding to listview like this listview1.ItemsSource = Empdata; it's strange why it create problems for you cause working fine for me... I can send you whole source code if you provide your email.

Comment: please check the above textbox code that i posted at first and the xaml code for gridview also been mentioned.. the c# code for the button click event is given above the xaml one..please check them..

Comment: Thanks a lot............i too have the same code but in the "Dataclass.cs"(which i used for defining get;set properties for the variables), i have overwritten the values for the Age property ..that is why i could not get that...now with declaring all those get;set properties in my main window() class has solved my Issue.....